# Horizontally align UILabel and UIImageView together inside of a full width UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a `UIView` in my layout that is pinned to the sides of my VC. Inside of that I have an icon `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` that is next to that. I would like both of those to be center aligned inside of the `UIView` no matter how long the text inside of the label is. (Similar to how you would use text-align:center; in CSS to align both image and text center).

```
|          UIView         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|     |image| |label|     |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
```

Sometimes the label might be long, but I still need them centered:

```
|          UIView         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|  |img| |label is long|  |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
```

[image]
[image]

I know how to use `Autolayout` but this one has me stumped since I can't created a "holder" `UIView` and center that. I need some help figuring out the constrains to add in IB.

Ideas?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you looking for code to setup the layout or are you having trouble setting up constraints in IB?

Comment: @rmaddy - Sorry, help with constraints in IB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on @Mahmoud Adam's answer, we can do this entirely in the storyboard.

1. Horizontal and vertical align the `UIView` relative to its superview.
2. Add constraints to the `UIImage` and `UILabel` so that they are pinned to the edges of the `UIView`.

The `UIView` will grow as the `UIImage` and `UILabel` grow inside of it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new `UIView` inside main view and put the `UUImageView` and `UILabel` inside it, this view should have the following constraints

using interface builder

1. Horizontal align inside the main view
2. Vertical align inside the main view (same as imageView now)

using code in the view controller

3. width = image.width + label.width + horizontal space between imageView & label
4. height = Max (image.height, label.height)

Comment: In step 3, do you mean set the constraint width for the holder `UIView`?

Comment: yeah, the `UIView` that will hold both the image the the label

Comment: You can do this entirely in the storyboard with constraints as well. Use step 1 and 2. Instead of 3 and 4, add constraints to the `UIImage` and `UILabel` in reference to the `UIView` they are now embedded in. If the `UIImage` and `UILabel` are pinned to the edges of the `UIView`, then the `UIView` will grow as the views inside it do.

Comment: @keithbhunter - That works! Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple i guess...using storyboard....

If you not found solution yet...then check this image and follow...

Here...green color background is `UIView` in image

[image]

and i select `update constraints` for view from `resolve autolayout views`